# Query for 1 to many table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I have a situation which can be referred to the table below:

```
TABLE A                       TABLE B         TABLE C   
ID  TOTAL_PRICE ORDER_ID        ID            ID    ORDER ID
1   10          101             101           1001  101
2   20          101             103           1002  101
3   25          103                           1003  103
4   10          103                           1004  103
```

With all these tables I'm expecting of this result:

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT         
ID  TOTAL_PRICE ORDER_ID    ID
1   10               101    1001
2   20               101    1002
3   25               103    1003
4   10               103    1004
```

And the result that I get follows:

```
REAL OUTPUT         
ID  TOTAL_PRICE ORDER_ID    ID
1   10               101    1001
1   10               101    1002
2   20               101    1001
2   20               101    1002
3   25               103    1003
3   25               103    1004
4   10               103    1003
4   10               103    1004
```

My sql as follows and I'm using SQL Oracle:

```
SELECT a.id, a.total_price, a.order.id, c.id
FROM a,b,c 
WHERE a.order_id=b.id AND b.id=c.order_id
```

With that situation, how can I solve the problem in order to get the expected output? Thank you.

Comment: Please better explain the logic behind your expected result; for example, the record with total_price = 25 has order_id with id 1003 and 1004 ( table C), so why do you only want 1003?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to assign one `id` from table `c` for each row from table `a` given your matching tables criteria. For this you could use `row_number` to enumerate your rows inside tables `a` and `c` and then assign this information with the row number respectively:

```
select
  a.id, a.total_price, a.order_id, c.id
from (select *, row_number over (partition by order_id order by id) as rn from a) a
join b on a.order_id = b.id
join (select id, order_id, row_number over (partition by order_id order by id) as rn from c) on b.id = c.order_id
where a.rn = c.rn
```

Comment: Yes definitely. This is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much